# How to interpret pprof output?

Tags: performance, go, pprof, heap-profiling

I'm trying to profile an application written in go which apparently uses about 256 virtual memory (checked using `ps aux`). I'm trying to use [pprof](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/) package and see what functions allocate/consume most of the memory but the results make no sense to me. `pprof top` seems to list only the runtime functions. Can someone help me understand this data?

```
ps aux |grep android
root      4584  3.4  0.1 500244 29536 pts/1    Sl+  17:21   0:38 ./android -logtostderr
```

go tool pprof http://localhost:6060/debug/pprof/heap

```
/pprof.localhost:6060.inuse_objects.inuse_space.008.pb.gz
Entering interactive mode (type "help" for commands)
(pprof) top
512.19kB of 512.19kB total (  100%)
Dropped 19 nodes (cum <= 2.56kB)
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
  512.19kB   100%   100%   512.19kB   100%  runtime.malg
         0     0%   100%   512.19kB   100%  runtime.mcommoninit
         0     0%   100%   512.19kB   100%  runtime.mpreinit
         0     0%   100%   512.19kB   100%  runtime.rt0_go
         0     0%   100%   512.19kB   100%  runtime.schedinit
(pprof)
```

http://localhost:6060/debug/pprof/heap?debug=1

```
heap profile: 3: 49632 [3: 49632] @ heap/1048576
1: 49152 [1: 49152] @ 0x412c62 0x411bc9 0x6fd8c8 0x649c40 0x5497e6 0x409ad2 0x43615f 0x4669c1
#   0x6fd8c8    html.init+0xe8          /usr/local/gosrc/src/html/entity.go:2154
#   0x649c40    html/template.init+0x70     /usr/local/gosrc/src/html/template/url.go:105
#   0x5497e6    net/http/pprof.init+0x56    /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/pprof/pprof.go:239
#   0x409ad2    main.init+0x92          /root/go/src/github.com/ginkoob/devmg/local/android/local.go:236
#   0x43615f    runtime.main+0x27f      /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/proc.go:100

1: 384 [1: 384] @ 0x43d0e7 0x4317ef 0x437700 0x4372a9 0x464182
#   0x43d0e7    runtime.malg+0x27       /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/proc1.go:2172
#   0x4317ef    runtime.mpreinit+0x1f       /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/os1_linux.go:197
#   0x437700    runtime.mcommoninit+0x100   /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/proc1.go:114
#   0x4372a9    runtime.schedinit+0x79      /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/proc1.go:57
#   0x464182    runtime.rt0_go+0x132        /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:109

1: 96 [1: 96] @ 0x449005 0x46a114 0x468625 0x467e71 0x4069d5 0x436190 0x4669c1
#   0x46a114    golang.org/x/mobile/gl.DoWork+0x54  /root/go/src/golang.org/x/mobile/gl/work.go:82
#   0x468625    golang.org/x/mobile/app.main+0x1d5  /root/go/src/golang.org/x/mobile/app/x11.go:65
#   0x467e71    golang.org/x/mobile/app.Main+0x21   /root/go/src/golang.org/x/mobile/app/app.go:22
#   0x4069d5    main.main+0x75              /root/go/src/github.com/ginkoob/devmg/local/android/local.go:65
#   0x436190    runtime.main+0x2b0          /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/proc.go:111

0: 0 [0: 0] @ 0x449005 0x6529f5 0x652936 0x64e2c4 0x54932e 0x549540 0x5222aa 0x523b0d 0x52457e 0x521d6e 0x4669c1
#   0x6529f5    runtime/pprof.writeGoroutineStacks+0x45 /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:514
#   0x652936    runtime/pprof.writeGoroutine+0x46   /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:505
#   0x64e2c4    runtime/pprof.(*Profile).WriteTo+0xd4   /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:236
#   0x54932e    net/http/pprof.handler.ServeHTTP+0x37e  /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/pprof/pprof.go:199
#   0x549540    net/http/pprof.Index+0x200      /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/pprof/pprof.go:211
#   0x5222aa    net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP+0x3a /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/server.go:1422
#   0x523b0d    net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP+0x17d    /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/server.go:1699
#   0x52457e    net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP+0x19e  /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/server.go:1862
#   0x521d6e    net/http.(*conn).serve+0xbee        /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/server.go:1361


# runtime.MemStats
# Alloc = 2701264
# TotalAlloc = 2701264
# Sys = 7145720
# Lookups = 18
# Mallocs = 19841
# Frees = 0
# HeapAlloc = 2701264
# HeapSys = 3637248
# HeapIdle = 262144
# HeapInuse = 3375104
# HeapReleased = 0
# HeapObjects = 19841
# Stack = 557056 / 557056
# MSpan = 28896 / 32768
# MCache = 4832 / 16384
# BuckHashSys = 1443979
# NextGC = 4194304
# PauseNs = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
# NumGC = 0
# EnableGC = true
# DebugGC = false
```

http://localhost:6060/debug/pprof/goroutine?debug=1

```
goroutine profile: total 31
1 @ 0x652ba8 0x652983 0x64e2c4 0x54932e 0x549540 0x5222aa 0x523b0d 0x52457e 0x521d6e 0x4669c1
#   0x652ba8    runtime/pprof.writeRuntimeProfile+0xb8  /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:545
#   0x652983    runtime/pprof.writeGoroutine+0x93   /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:507
#   0x64e2c4    runtime/pprof.(*Profile).WriteTo+0xd4   /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:236
#   0x54932e    net/http/pprof.handler.ServeHTTP+0x37e  /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/pprof/pprof.go:199
#   0x549540    net/http/pprof.Index+0x200      /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/pprof/pprof.go:211
#   0x5222aa    net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP+0x3a /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/server.go:1422
#   0x523b0d    net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP+0x17d    /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/server.go:1699
#   0x52457e    net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP+0x19e  /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/server.go:1862
#   0x521d6e    net/http.(*conn).serve+0xbee        /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/server.go:1361

1 @ 0x436573 0x444ce4 0x444242 0x46871a 0x467e71 0x4069d5 0x436190 0x4669c1
#   0x46871a    golang.org/x/mobile/app.main+0x2ca  /root/go/src/golang.org/x/mobile/app/x11.go:61
#   0x467e71    golang.org/x/mobile/app.Main+0x21   /root/go/src/golang.org/x/mobile/app/app.go:22
#   0x4069d5    main.main+0x75              /root/go/src/github.com/nme/devmg/local/android/local.go:65
#   0x436190    runtime.main+0x2b0          /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/proc.go:111

1 @ 0x4669c1

1 @ 0x436573 0x436634 0x436378 0x4669c1
#   0x436573    runtime.gopark+0x163        /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/proc.go:186
#   0x436634    runtime.goparkunlock+0x54   /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/proc.go:191
#   0x436378    runtime.forcegchelper+0xb8  /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/proc.go:152

1 @ 0x436573 0x436634 0x42630d 0x4669c1
#   0x436573    runtime.gopark+0x163        /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/proc.go:186
#   0x436634    runtime.goparkunlock+0x54   /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/proc.go:191
#   0x42630d    runtime.bgsweep+0x14d       /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/mgcsweep.go:67

1 @ 0x436573 0x436634 0x41e04a 0x4669c1
#   0x436573    runtime.gopark+0x163        /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/proc.go:186
#   0x436634    runtime.goparkunlock+0x54   /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/proc.go:191
#   0x41e04a    runtime.runfinq+0xaa        /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/mfinal.go:154

1 @ 0x436573 0x444ce4 0x444242 0x4691e7 0x4669c1
#   0x4691e7    golang.org/x/mobile/app.pump.func1+0x527    /root/go/src/golang.org/x/mobile/app/app.go:138

1 @ 0x436573 0x436634 0x40d611 0x40ccfb 0x4acb57 0x4669c1
#   0x4acb57    github.com/golang/glog.(*loggingT).flushDaemon+0x67 /root/go/src/github.com/golang/glog/glog.go:882

1 @ 0x4173be 0x45142e 0x4669c1
#   0x4173be    runtime.notetsleepg+0x4e    /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/lock_futex.go:203
#   0x45142e    runtime.timerproc+0xde      /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/time.go:209

1 @ 0x436573 0x444ce4 0x444242 0x533327 0x4669c1
#   0x533327    net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop+0xac7  /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/transport.go:983

1 @ 0x436573 0x43069e 0x42fb60 0x4cd99a 0x4cda06 0x4d158c 0x4ef94d 0x5254d1 0x524853 0x524716 0x524daf 0x408e1c 0x4669c1
#   0x42fb60    net.runtime_pollWait+0x60           /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/netpoll.go:157
#   0x4cd99a    net.(*pollDesc).Wait+0x3a           /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73
#   0x4cda06    net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead+0x36           /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:78
#   0x4d158c    net.(*netFD).accept+0x27c           /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/fd_unix.go:408
#   0x4ef94d    net.(*TCPListener).AcceptTCP+0x4d       /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:254
#   0x5254d1    net/http.tcpKeepAliveListener.Accept+0x41   /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/server.go:2138
#   0x524853    net/http.(*Server).Serve+0xb3           /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/server.go:1887
#   0x524716    net/http.(*Server).ListenAndServe+0x136     /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/server.go:1877
#   0x524daf    net/http.ListenAndServe+0x8f            /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/server.go:1967
#   0x408e1c    main.main.func1+0x3c                /root/go/src/github.com/nme/devmg/local/android/local.go:40

1 @ 0x436573 0x43069e 0x42fb60 0x4cd99a 0x4cda06 0x4cf74a 0x4e3c34 0x5c0c39 0x5c14aa 0x4b0cee 0x4b5b43 0x49e028 0x49a8d0 0x49b173 0x49cf47 0x4669c1
#   0x42fb60    net.runtime_pollWait+0x60                       /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/netpoll.go:157
#   0x4cd99a    net.(*pollDesc).Wait+0x3a                       /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73
#   0x4cda06    net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead+0x36                       /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:78
#   0x4cf74a    net.(*netFD).Read+0x23a                         /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/fd_unix.go:232
#   0x4e3c34    net.(*conn).Read+0xe4                           /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/net.go:132
#   0x5c0c39    bufio.(*Reader).fill+0x1e9                      /usr/local/gosrc/src/bufio/bufio.go:97
#   0x5c14aa    bufio.(*Reader).ReadByte+0x7a                       /usr/local/gosrc/src/bufio/bufio.go:229
#   0x4b0cee    golang.org/x/net/websocket.hybiFrameReaderFactory.NewFrameReader+0xbe   /root/go/src/golang.org/x/net/websocket/hybi.go:126
#   0x4b5b43    golang.org/x/net/websocket.Codec.Receive+0x183              /root/go/src/golang.org/x/net/websocket/websocket.go:315
#   0x49e028    golang.org/x/net/websocket.(Codec).Receive-fm+0x58          /root/go/src/github.com/nme/socks/ws.go:420
#   0x49a8d0    github.com/nme/socks.(*WSConn).execute+0x210            /root/go/src/github.com/nme/socks/ws.go:389
#   0x49b173    github.com/nme/socks.(*WSConn).receiveMessage+0x203         /root/go/src/github.com/nme/socks/ws.go:420
#   0x49cf47    github.com/nme/socks.(*WSConn).Setup.func3+0x117            /root/go/src/github.com/nme/socks/ws.go:221

1 @ 0x436573 0x436634 0x40d611 0x40ccfb 0x4080af 0x406fd8 0x4092e7 0x46937f 0x4669c1
#   0x4080af    main.startSocks+0x3bf           /root/go/src/github.com/nme/devmg/local/android/local.go:151
#   0x406fd8    main.startClient+0x5d8          /root/go/src/github.com/nme/devmg/local/android/local.go:82
#   0x4092e7    main.main.func2+0x227           /root/go/src/github.com/nme/devmg/local/android/local.go:64
#   0x46937f    golang.org/x/mobile/app.main.func1+0x6f /root/go/src/golang.org/x/mobile/app/x11.go:51

1 @ 0x436573 0x444ce4 0x444242 0x533c4c 0x4669c1
#   0x533c4c    net/http.(*persistConn).writeLoop+0x40c /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/transport.go:1016

1 @ 0x436573 0x436634 0x40d182 0x40ccfb 0x408f63 0x4669c1
#   0x408f63    main.main.func2.1+0x73  /root/go/src/github.com/nme/devmg/local/android/local.go:47

1 @ 0x436573 0x444ce4 0x444242 0x49dcee 0x4669c1
#   0x49dcee    github.com/nme/socks.(*WSConn).Setup.func4+0x86e    /root/go/src/github.com/nme/socks/ws.go:256

1 @ 0x436573 0x444ce4 0x444242 0x49c7a5 0x4669c1
#   0x49c7a5    github.com/nme/socks.SetKeepAlive.func1+0x215   /root/go/src/github.com/nme/socks/ws.go:32

1 @ 0x436573 0x436634 0x40d611 0x40ccfb 0x4072c6 0x4669c1
#   0x4072c6    main.WaitCmd+0xc6   /root/go/src/github.com/nme/devmg/local/android/local.go:95

1 @ 0x436573 0x444ce4 0x444242 0x4998aa 0x4669c1
#   0x4998aa    github.com/nme/socks.(*Router).ListenAndServe+0x91a /root/go/src/github.com/nme/socks/ws.go:124

1 @ 0x436573 0x444ce4 0x444242 0x49a173 0x4669c1
#   0x49a173    github.com/nme/socks.(*WSConn).Setup+0x753  /root/go/src/github.com/nme/socks/ws.go:186

1 @ 0x436573 0x436634 0x40d611 0x40ccfb 0x49b3ea 0x4669c1
#   0x49b3ea    github.com/nme/socks.(*Nic).Dial.func1+0x9a /root/go/src/github.com/nme/socks/conn.go:34

3 @ 0x436573 0x444ce4 0x444242 0x49cd50 0x4669c1
#   0x49cd50    github.com/nme/socks.(*Router).ListenAndServe.func1+0x590   /root/go/src/github.com/nme/socks/ws.go:96

1 @ 0x436573 0x43069e 0x42fb60 0x4cd99a 0x4cda06 0x4cf74a 0x4e3c34 0x51a734 0x581f7d 0x5c0c39 0x5c1aaa 0x5c1b23 0x6285f1 0x628360 0x515496 0x51d83f 0x5218a7 0x4669c1
#   0x42fb60    net.runtime_pollWait+0x60           /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/netpoll.go:157
#   0x4cd99a    net.(*pollDesc).Wait+0x3a           /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73
#   0x4cda06    net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead+0x36           /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:78
#   0x4cf74a    net.(*netFD).Read+0x23a             /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/fd_unix.go:232
#   0x4e3c34    net.(*conn).Read+0xe4               /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/net.go:132
#   0x51a734    net/http.(*liveSwitchReader).Read+0xa4      /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/server.go:219
#   0x581f7d    io.(*LimitedReader).Read+0xbd           /usr/local/gosrc/src/io/io.go:427
#   0x5c0c39    bufio.(*Reader).fill+0x1e9          /usr/local/gosrc/src/bufio/bufio.go:97
#   0x5c1aaa    bufio.(*Reader).ReadSlice+0x21a         /usr/local/gosrc/src/bufio/bufio.go:328
#   0x5c1b23    bufio.(*Reader).ReadLine+0x53           /usr/local/gosrc/src/bufio/bufio.go:357
#   0x6285f1    net/textproto.(*Reader).readLineSlice+0x81  /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/textproto/reader.go:55
#   0x628360    net/textproto.(*Reader).ReadLine+0x40       /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/textproto/reader.go:36
#   0x515496    net/http.ReadRequest+0xb6           /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/request.go:653
#   0x51d83f    net/http.(*conn).readRequest+0x32f      /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/server.go:633
#   0x5218a7    net/http.(*conn).serve+0x727            /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/server.go:1319

1 @ 0x436573 0x43069e 0x42fb60 0x4cd99a 0x4cda06 0x4cf74a 0x4e3c34 0x51a734 0x581f7d 0x5c0c39 0x5c0e5c 0x51d7cb 0x5218a7 0x4669c1
#   0x42fb60    net.runtime_pollWait+0x60       /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/netpoll.go:157
#   0x4cd99a    net.(*pollDesc).Wait+0x3a       /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73
#   0x4cda06    net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead+0x36       /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:78
#   0x4cf74a    net.(*netFD).Read+0x23a         /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/fd_unix.go:232
#   0x4e3c34    net.(*conn).Read+0xe4           /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/net.go:132
#   0x51a734    net/http.(*liveSwitchReader).Read+0xa4  /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/server.go:219
#   0x581f7d    io.(*LimitedReader).Read+0xbd       /usr/local/gosrc/src/io/io.go:427
#   0x5c0c39    bufio.(*Reader).fill+0x1e9      /usr/local/gosrc/src/bufio/bufio.go:97
#   0x5c0e5c    bufio.(*Reader).Peek+0xcc       /usr/local/gosrc/src/bufio/bufio.go:132
#   0x51d7cb    net/http.(*conn).readRequest+0x2bb  /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/server.go:629
#   0x5218a7    net/http.(*conn).serve+0x727        /usr/local/gosrc/src/net/http/server.go:1319

1 @ 0x436573 0x436634 0x42051b 0x4669c1
#   0x436573    runtime.gopark+0x163        /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/proc.go:186
#   0x436634    runtime.goparkunlock+0x54   /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/proc.go:191
#   0x42051b    runtime.backgroundgc+0x8b   /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/mgc.go:894

4 @ 0x436573 0x421717 0x4669c1
#   0x436573    runtime.gopark+0x163        /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/proc.go:186
#   0x421717    runtime.gcBgMarkWorker+0xf7 /usr/local/gosrc/src/runtime/mgc.go:1283
```

4584 is the PID of the application.
cat /proc/4584/status

```
Name:   android
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   4584
Ngid:   0
Pid:    4584
PPid:   2776
TracerPid:  0
Uid:    0   0   0   0
Gid:    0   0   0   0
FDSize: 256
Groups: 0 
NStgid: 4584
NSpid:  4584
NSpgid: 4584
NSsid:  2776
VmPeak:   631316 kB
VmSize:   573976 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:     30060 kB
VmRSS:     29344 kB
VmData:   487492 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
VmExe:      6704 kB
VmLib:     13404 kB
VmPTE:       288 kB
VmPMD:        20 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
Threads:    10
SigQ:   3/62942
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000000000000
SigCgt: ffffffffffc1feff
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000003fffffffff
CapEff: 0000003fffffffff
CapBnd: 0000003fffffffff
Seccomp:    0
Cpus_allowed:   f
Cpus_allowed_list:  0-3
Mems_allowed:   00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000001
Mems_allowed_list:  0
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    531158
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 13254
```

Answer (score 3):

Bradfitz does a great talk on how to profile go programs using tools such as pprof.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxDZuPEgbBU&feature=youtu.be

Here's the info from the talk on his github:

https://github.com/bradfitz/talk-yapc-asia-2015/blob/master/talk.md

Hope that helps!

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's a great site with people helping each other. Personally, I'm a profiler-skeptic, instead beating the drum for [*random pausing*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771). For example, in Bradfitz's example, the first thing he finds costs 95% of time. What I would do is wrap a loop around the top level code so it takes enough time to manually sample. I would make sure I saw the problem on 2 or more samples. Each sample would have a 95% chance of seeing the problem, so it wouldn't take many samples. Then I would fix it and afterward measure the speedup.

Comment: I am pretty sure that neither the talk nor the github contain any information on how to interpret the output of http://localhost:6060/debug/pprof/heap?debug=1.   Please point specifically the time of the talk or the line in the github where this is mentioned.

Comment: @DraifKroneg Around https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxDZuPEgbBU&feature=youtu.be&t=1475 they generate a memoryprofile from running a test and store that data to prof.mem. They then process that file with go tool pprof. The output of localhost:6060/debug/pprof/heap?debug=1 is in the same format as the prof.mem file, so the same process of using the tool to dive into it applies.

I personally find dumping the output to SVG and viewing that in a browser (as Brad does) is the easiest way to understand the output. Directly reading the prof.mem file format sounds not fun, I'd stick to the tooling.